# Is it possible to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-(\pi \tan(x) - 1)^2} \, dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

How to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-(\pi \tan(x) - 1)^2} \, dx$$
Source: I created this integral so I don’t know the closed form

I tried Wolfram Alpha, but Wolfram Alpha is unable to evaluate it.

Let $ u = \tan(x)$, then  $du = \sec^2(x) dx$. When $x = 0$, $ u = \tan(0) = 0$, and when $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$,  $u = \tan(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \infty $

Now, the integral becomes:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(\pi u - 1)^2} \frac{du}{\cos^2(x)}$$

Now,  $\cos^2(x)$ in terms of $u$. Since $\tan^2(x) + 1 = \sec^2(x)$, we have $1 + u^2 = \sec^2(x)$, and thus  $\cos^2(x) = \frac{1}{1+u^2}$.

Substituting;

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(\pi u - 1)^2} \frac{du}{1+u^2}$$

Comment: Is this a textbook question or just random.

Comment: @SisantaChhatoi I created this integral

Comment: Have you tried plotting it on desmos and get some clue

Comment: @SisantaChhatoi no I will try

Comment: Ya because from a certain part of the limit the function becomes 0.

Comment: I see no reason to think there is a closed form in terms of standard functions.

Comment: @GEdgar Wolfram's inability to evaluate it does not mean that the closed form does not exist, but perhaps we can try.

Comment: At least [Wolfram-Alpha do takes the numerical evaluation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_0%5E%7Bpi%2F2%7D+e%5E%28-%28pi*tan%28x%29-1%29%5E2%29*dx)

Comment: using $z=\pi\tan(x)-1$ and that this implies $\sec^2(x) \equiv 1+\left(\frac{z+1}{\pi}\right)^2$ you get the equivalent integral $$\int\limits_{-1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{\pi e^{-z^2}}{\pi^2+(z+1)^2}\ dz$$ which is like the spectrum of a convolution of a Gaussian function with some bounded decreasing exponential... don't know if some closed form follows, but looks simpler that the ones you posted

Comment: I upvoted this question, mainly to counter the downvotes.